# NSRegularExpression, specify case-sensitive match?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsregularexpression

Is there a way using `NSRegularExpression` to specify that you want to do a case-sensitive search? I am trying to match the upper-case TAG "ACL" in the text below. The pattern I am using is simply:

```
// Pattern
[A-Z]+

// SearchText
<td align=\"left\" nowrap><font face=\"courier, monospace\" size=\"-1\">ACL*</font></td>

// Code:
NSString *textBuffer = @"<td align=\"left\" nowrap><font face=\"courier, monospace\" size=\"-1\">ACL*</font></td>";
NSString *pattern = @"([A-Z]+)";
NSRegularExpression *regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regExp firstMatchInString:textBuffer options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [textBuffer length])];
NSLog(@"OBJECT CLASS: %@", [textBuffer substringWithRange:[result range]]);
```

**Output:** (with case-Insensative I am getting the first "td" as expected, when what I really want is "ACL"

I know that `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` is wrong, I was hoping there would be a `NSRegularExpressionCaseSensitive`. Also there is a flagOption `?(i)` that also specifies a case-insensitive search but again nothing for case-sensative. What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Case sensitive is the default. Dont put the insensitive flag in there.

Comment: Thank you, it does work if you replace NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive with 0, just seems strange that there is not a dedicated option for it.

Comment: @fuzzygoat There's no such option because case-sensitive search, being faster, is the default option.

Comment: @fuzzygoat example in Swift: `NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^@[a-z]+", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(rawValue: 0))`